# How does the garbage collector in R work?

Tags: r, garbage-collection

I have the following assumptions:

1. For the garbage collection the reference count of an object is used, i.e. how many names are assigned with the object.
2. If an object has 0 references the garbage collector is used.

However in a talk by Hadley wickham he said, that R only knows whether an object has 1 or more than 1 reference, therefore  once it had more than 2 references it can never get down to 0 references.

So my question is: How does the garbage collector work in R?

Comment: Was this talk from before R 4.0?

Comment: Likely a look at `help(gc)`, `help(Memory)`, `help(gctorture)` and `help(req.finalizer)` will give you the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

As @Roland said, R 4.0.0 [introduced reference counting](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html) (scroll to "R 4.0.0") which replaces the so-called [`NAMED mechanism`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#The-_0027data_0027). This mechanism indeed works with the values 0, 1, 2 like you write in your assumptions.

However, the main purpose of the NAMED mechanism seems to me to enable [modify-in-place](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#modify-in-place) when an object is assigned to only one name, not to find unreferenced objects.

So this is not a complete answer but it helped me at least partially. Maybe another one can complete the part how the GC finds the objects that are not referenced anymore

Comment: R maintains essentially 'linked lists' of SEXP that are available or that have been assigned. During garbage collection R scans the list of SEXP to see if the assigned SEXP are referenced. If not, the SEXP is transferred to the unassigned list. The garbage collector uses 'generations', so recently allocated SEXP (e.g., during a function call) are scanned for continued reference more frequently. See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#The-write-barrier for one introduction

Comment: @MartinMorgan Why not just delete the object if REFCNT == 0? Is it for safety reasons, in case REFCNT is wrong?

Comment: @thc it's likely the complexity of actually determining the REFCNT -- `x = 1; rm(x)` is easy, so is `f = function() { x <- 1; y }; f()`. But `g = function() { x; environment() }; h = g()` still holds a reference to `x` even after `f()` has been evaluated.